# No search result on Github Issue tracker?

Tags: github

I started using a personal github. I didn't push any codes up yet; I only played with the issue tracker.

I created few issues but found out that the "search" function doesn't return any search result doesn't matter what keyword I type in. I went to someone's repository and tested their issue tracker and I can search without any problem.

Is this a bug or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter a new issue, you usually can't search for it right away. It takes time for the issue to be indexed and included in the search engine results.

Github most likely won't be indexing all data on their site continually but periodically. So the best advice is to check back later and try again. If it still doesn't show up, it may be a bug in Github.